# DNN skin CSS style 404 error

Tags: css, http-status-code-404, dotnetnuke

I' creating custom skin I have the 404 come from  CSS files skin  the error in gooogle chrome  java-script console. i don't have problem in applying the style.just I want to remove the error.

```
GET http://localhost/ideapark/Portals/_default/skins/ideapark_bootstrap/css/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found) LogViewer.aspx:11
GET http://localhost/ideapark/Portals/_default/skins/ideapark_bootstrap/css/css/css/lts.css 404 (Not Found) LogViewer.aspx:11
GET http://localhost/ideapark/Portals/_default/skins/ideapark_bootstrap/css/css/bootstrapselect.min.css 404 (Not Found) LogViewer.aspx:11
include Css on Skin
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="bootstrapCSS" runat="server" FilePath="css/bootstrap.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="14" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="DnnCssInclude1" runat="server" FilePath="css/lts.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="13" />
<dnn:DnnCssInclude ID="DnnCssInclude2" runat="server" FilePath="css/bootstrapselect.min.css" PathNameAlias="SkinPath" Priority="12" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the error has to do with the /css/css path. Where are the Skin's ASCX files stored at?

If you try to load the URLs in a browser which one works

```
http://localhost/ideapark/Portals/_default/skins/ideapark_bootstrap/css/css/bootstrap.min.css 
http://localhost/ideapark/Portals/_default/skins/ideapark_bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

Comment: Hi it is located in dnnLocation\Portals\_default\Skins\Ideapark_Bootstrap

Comment: So you will want to figure out why the /css/css entry is getting added via DNN. You might move the CSS file up to the main skin folder, instead of in the CSS folder just for testing purposes.

Comment: I find the problem out the designer add @import url(css/lts.css); on heade of css file